# Canada: will my student visa still be valid after I finish my studies?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa, driving-license

I am a Swiss citizen and I used to be a student in UBC, Vancouver, Canada. I finished my PhD recently and moved back to Switzerland. For various reasons, I need to get back to Vancouver at some point. When doing, I would like to take advantage to pass my driving license (which I could not pass before leaving because the offices were closed as a measure against covid-19).

In order to pass a driving license, I will need a valid student visa. My visa is valid until summer 2021 and I am hoping that until then, the covid-19 measures will relax and I will be able to make my trip to Vancouver.

Can I enter Canada with a student visa even if I am not a registered student anymore? If not, then I could enter the country as a tourist but I am worried then that my visa could be somehow nullified when I pass the border and that I would not be able to use my visa as ID to pass my driver's license. Would crossing entering Canada as a tourist nullify my student visa?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your questions, but will offer a reframing comment. Given the cost (RT airfare from Switzerland to BC and return), and several days of your time, and lodging and food costs, all for an uncertain result (cf. your previous question: expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20946/…), it might be cheaper and would certainly be less time-consuming to engage the drivers license process in Switzerland, where you actually live.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I appreciate the advice but 1) I have to get back to Vancouver at some point anyway, I am just hopping i can take advantage of it to resolve my situation with my driver's license in the same time. 2) No, there is no way it is cheaper and there is no way it would less time consuming. A driver's license (including the so called L2 phase) cost a good 2000CHF in Switzerland (and I would not have any accommodation cost in Vancouver).

Comment: Very good then. Please do check in again here and let us know what happens.